# get key by value in dictionary with same value in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume a dictionary

```
d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':1}
```

When I use

```
d.keys()[d.values(). index(1)]
```

I get `'a'`,but i want get `'c'` as well ,since the value of `'c'` is also 1. How can i do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, like this

```
print [key for key in d if d[key] == 1]
```

It iterates through the keys of the dictionary and checks if the value is `1`. If the value is 1, it adds the corresponding key to the list.

Alternatively you can use, `dict.iteritems()` in Python 2.7, like this

```
print [key for key, value in d.iteritems() if value == 1]
```

In Python 3.x, you would do the same with `dict.items()`,

```
print([key for key, value in d.items() if value == 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

For a one-shot, thefourtheye's answer is the most obvious and straightforward solution. Now if you need to lookup more than one value, you may want to build a "reverse index" instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def reverse(d):
     r = defaultdict(list)
     for k, v in d.items():
         r[v].append(k)
     return r

d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':1}
index = reverse(d)
print index[1]  
=> ['a', 'c']
print index[2]
=> ['b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function to see all the keys in the dict that have the value you want.

```
d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':1}
x = filter(lambda k: d[k]==1, d.keys())
print x
['a', 'c']
```

I don't know if it is any more efficient than the manual loop; probably not.  But it's more compact and clearer.